# yourContext.Configuration not available

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

On an earlier post, I read about setting:

```
yourContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
yourContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

To improve  bulk insert performance.  I am using Entity Framework 5.0, but can not find the `yourContext.Configuration` object.  When I select my context, I only see `ContextOptions`, but not Configuration.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Please show your dbContext class. And where you try `yourContext.Configuration`

Comment: I generated the class from my database.  Here is the context:

Comment: public FandbEntities1(string connectionString) : base(connectionString, "FandbEntities1")
        {
            this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            OnContextCreated();
        }

Comment: There's not such a thing as `ContextOptions` in an EF5 `DbContext` and there *is* a `Configuration` property. This `yourContext` is *not* an EF5 `DbContext`subclass. The question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

I was using EF Core and found `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` under `ChangeTracker`:

`context.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false`

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to work with context is to define a class that derives from DbContext .
Its an abstract of your database. And exposes DbSet properties that represent collections of the specified entities in the context.

For example :

```
using System.Data.Entity;

public class ProductContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; } 
}
```

Then you can do like this

```
using (var context = new ProductContext())
{
     context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
}
```